# How to use pycaffe to train my own dataset of images?

Tags: dataset, pycaffe

I am very new and just started using pycaffe after installing it from [How To Install Caffe, CUDA and Fast-RCNN - A guide for all](http://sungyulkim11.blogspot.sg/2016/01/how-to-install-caffe-cuda-and-fast-rcnn.html)

And now I will like to know if there's any online step by step guide on can I edit the files and use it for my own dataset of images. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: if you want to train a CNN classifier using caffe, [this](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2016/06/introduction-deep-learning-python-caffe/) link is really comprehensive.

Comment: Thank you for your introduction! @R.K.Tayal I will give it a try